# How to get data from codeigniter controller using Angularjs $http

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

The following Codeigniter controller outputs a JSON when accessed through url.

Codeigniter controller

```html
function ttoday(){
$this->load->model('dashboard_stats');
$tours_today = $this->dashboard_stats->upcoming_tours();
$data_json = json_encode($tours_today);
echo $data_json;     
}
```

Codeigniter Model

```html
function upcoming_tours()
{
  mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+3:00'");
  $this->db->order_by('from_start_time','asc');
  $this->db->where('DATE(from_start_time) = CURDATE()');
  $this->db->where('from_start_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 MINUTE)');
  $query = $this->db->get('tours');
  return $query->result();

}
```

Angularjs Controller

```html
translineClassic.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope){
 
 $http.get('http://122.222.22.2/booking/public_html/admin/api/cities')
 .success(function(result){
  $scope.cities = result;
 });

 $http.get('http://122.222.22.2/booking/public_html/admin/api/ttoday')
 .success(function(result){
  $scope.tours = result;
 });
}]);
```

Encoded Json

```html
[{"tour_id":"4260","route_time":"121473438600","tour_route":"12","from_start_time":"2016-09-09 19:30:00","available_seats":"47","start_price":"800.00","additional":"0","book_online":"0","date_created":"2016-08-30 09:50:05"},{"tour_id":"4412","route_time":"111473438600","tour_route":"11","from_start_time":"2016-09-09 19:30:00","available_seats":"47","start_price":"800.00","additional":"0","book_online":"0","date_created":"2016-08-30 11:34:46"}]
```

In the database where the routes are stored. We have stored the tour_route id and not the route name. There is a separate table that stores the routes, and I can get the route name by using the following code.

```html
function get_route_name($id){
  $this->db->select('route_name');
  $this->db->where('route_id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get('routes');
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
     $row = $query->row();
     return $row->route_name;
  }

 }
```

Using the code as shown above, I can be able to use the `$http` for angularjs to get the data and then bind with the view.

The problem arises when I need to show the route name. but instead I have tour_route, I can be able to do this in `php` using the `get_route_name()` function, How can I print route name instead of tour_route? Do I have to use the `$http` again? Please help me on this. I am new to angularJs and any help will be appreciated.

My View

```html
<article class="result">
        <div ng-repeat="tour in tours">
   <div class="one-fourth heightfix"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/translinebus.JPEG" alt="" /></div>
   <div class="one-half heightfix">
    <h3>{{ tour.tour_route }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" class="trigger color" title="Read more">?</a></h3>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <span class="ico people"></span>
      <p>Max people</strong> <br/>
      Seats Remaining </strong> </p>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="ico luggage"></span>
      <p>Max <strong>3 suitcases</strong> <br />per vehicle</p>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="ico time"></span>
      <p>Departure Time<br />
       <strong><span class="icon-clock" style="color:red;">
                     {{ tour.from_start_time }} </span>  
       </strong></p>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="one-fourth heightfix">
    <div>
             <div class="price"><small>KES</small> {{ tour.start_price }}</div>
     <span class="meta">per passenger</span>
                    <button value="{{ tour.tour_id }}" type="submit" class="btn grey large">select</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="full-width information" ng-show="showDetails"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close color" title="Close">x</a>
    <p>Free Wifi, Charging</p>
   </div>
  </div>

   </article>
```